# Reusable UITableViewCell duplicating on scroll in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Revisiting some old code I once did to start learning how code works when developing iOS applications so I apologize for the godlike viewController.  The problem when running the app is that once a user begins to scroll the tableview, the labels are beginning to duplicate on top of each other and I'm pretty sure the webviews are most likely stacking as well.  I've tried changing the code where I add the subviews in the cell by using the cell.contentview.addsubview() method but that doesn't change the stacking behavior when scrolling.  I'm using the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier() method as well which I thought clears out cells all together once it goes off screen.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated as I'm still learning.  Thank you in advance.

[image: Sample Screenshot]

```
import UIKit

class VimeoFeedViewController: UIViewController, NSXMLParserDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIWebViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate
{

    @IBOutlet var tbData: UITableView?

    var parser = NSXMLParser()
    var posts = NSMutableArray()
    var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
    var element = NSString()
    var title1 = NSMutableString()
    var date = NSMutableString()
    var link = NSMutableString()
    var webView = UIWebView()
    var boxView = UIView()
    var selectedCell = NSIndexPath()
    var valueToPass:String!
    var viewToPass: UIView!
    var customWebView = UIWebView()
    var url = NSURL()





    //custom code for webviews to show up
    var postTitle: String = String()
    var postLink: String = String()
    var ename: String = String()
    //end of custom code for webviews to show up

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.beginParsing()
        self.tbData?.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "home-page-background.png")!)
        webView.delegate = self

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func beginParsing()
    {
        posts = []
        parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:(NSURL(string:"https://vimeo.com/channels/1000464/videos/rss"))!)!
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
        tbData!.reloadData()

    }

    //XMLParser Methods

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
    {
        element = elementName
        if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item")
        {
            elements = NSMutableDictionary()
            elements = [:]
            title1 = NSMutableString()
            title1 = ""
            date = NSMutableString()
            date = ""
            link = NSMutableString()
            link = ""
            postTitle = String()
            postLink = String()

        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?)
    {
        if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item") {
            if !title1.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(title1, forKey: "title")
            }
            if !date.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(date, forKey: "date")
            }
            if !link.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(link, forKey: "link")
            }

            posts.addObject(elements)
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
    {
        if element.isEqualToString("title") {
            title1.appendString(string)
        }
        if element.isEqualToString("pubDate") {
            date.appendString(string)
        }
        if element.isEqualToString("link") {
            link.appendString(string)
        }
    }

    //Tableview Methods
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 100.0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))
        let imageName = "broughtToYouAG.png"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 420, height: 91)
        headerView.addSubview(imageView)
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "home-page-background.png")!)
        return headerView
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")!
        if(cell.isEqual(NSNull)) {
            cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Cell", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! UITableViewCell;
        }
        //start of customization
        let textLabelCustom = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 0, 200, 91))
        let detailTextLabelCustom = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 0, 200, 20))
        let customWebView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(245, 5, 149, 80))

        let url: NSURL? = NSURL(string: posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("link") as! NSString as String)



        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        customWebView.loadRequest(request)
        customWebView.delegate = self
        customWebView.scalesPageToFit = true



        cell.contentView.addSubview(customWebView)
        cell.contentView.addSubview(boxView)
        //cell.addSubview(customWebView)
        //cell.addSubview(boxView)



        textLabelCustom.text = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("title") as! NSString as String

        textLabelCustom.numberOfLines = 4
        detailTextLabelCustom.numberOfLines = 2
        textLabelCustom.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        detailTextLabelCustom.font = UIFont(name: "AmericanTypewriter", size: 15)
        textLabelCustom.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18)
        //cell.addSubview(textLabelCustom)
        cell.contentView.addSubview(textLabelCustom)
        //cell.addSubview(detailTextLabelCustom)
        cell.contentView.addSubview(detailTextLabelCustom)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "home-page-background.png")!)
        let backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "tableselectedimage.png")!)
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView
        return cell as UITableViewCell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
        let indexPath = tbData!.indexPathForSelectedRow;
        let url: NSURL? = NSURL(string: posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row).valueForKey("link") as! NSString as String)
        print("Video url selected: \(url)!")

    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "vimeoWebSegue") {
            //get a reference to the destination view controller
            let destinationVC: playingThatVideoViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! playingThatVideoViewController

            let indexPath = tbData!.indexPathForSelectedRow;

             let url: NSURL? = NSURL(string: posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row).valueForKey("link") as! NSString as String)

            let titlegoing = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row).valueForKey("title") as! NSString as String

            //set properties on the destination view controller
            destinationVC.videoWebView = customWebView
            destinationVC.urlbrought = url!
            destinationVC.titlebrought = titlegoing

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a custom UITableViewCell with desirable views (in your case 2 UILabels and UIWebView), load this cell from nib in cellForRowAtIndexPath and set needed values from arrays at indexPath.row appropriately. Don't create and add views in cellForRowAtIndexPath, just set values.

Comment: That sounds pretty straightforward and will try this next.  Thank you

Comment: This is a better answer than adding views in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and then either removing them and re-adding them on recycling, or telling if you've already added them. Set up a cell prototype in your Storyboard, tag it with the desired identifier, and give that custom subclass of UITableViewCell outlets to your custom views. Then simply cast the cell to the correct type and reference the outlets of the cells.

Comment: This approach is appropriate only when you have static number of views in a cell. What if the number of views in the cell are dynamic? In that case, you have to add views programmatically as @HandheldArchitect did in the question. So, coming again to the question, I'm facing the same issue drawing sub views multiple times in the cell. Is there a solution to this issue

Answer (score 1):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath, since the cells for reused (hence the method name 'reusableCell'), you'll have to remove all the cell's subviews before you add more subviews to the cell.

```
for subview in cell.contentView.subviews {
    subview.contentView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: How do you remove subviews before they are reused?

Comment: Wrong Programming Practice, 
You should never remove cell's subView not even in `didEndDisplayingCell` method. Instead of this use `cell.contentView.removeAllSubviews()` in `didEndDisplayingCell`

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier() method as well which
>   I thought clears out cells all together once it goes off screen

It does not clear the cells.

It reuses cells that go off screen to display the cells that come on screen.
You should be removing the views before adding them again. 
One way to accomplish this would be setting a tag for the view (`view.tag = 10`), and when dequeing a cell you cand do `cell.contentView.viewWithTag(10)?.removeFromSuperview()`.

Comment: When you say "before adding them again"....I'm not quite sure what you mean by this because I only called the addSubview method once for each piece of content.  How does one go about clearing a cell?  tableView.reloadData()???

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers suggest that you remove and re-add the views. Id rather suggest you add them once, and reuse the views. Subclass your cell and add the subviews once. Then use [prepareForReuse](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse) to clear the text label.text = nil, for example.

> For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state.

Comment: Thank you so much, I saw the prepareForReuse method in UITableViews documentation but I'm unsure if it would need to go inside viewdidload or stand on its own as its own function and the tableViewController will call the method automatically?  I hope what I just said makes sense, if it doesn't I apologize.

Comment: @TheAtlantaGoat The viewDidLoad method belongs to a ViewController, what you need to do is to create a UITableViewCell subclass, thats where the method gets called. I'm not coding in swift unfortunatly can't show you an example, but here is a good tutorial I found for you that shows you how to subclass a tableviewCell and use it correctly in a tableview. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adP2dG_C1XU , basically the idea is you create the outlet/property ONCE and just change its content/text/image when you reuse the cells.

Answer (score 1):

There are Two Possible Reason of this bug.

**Reason 1**

in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method
you are creating two labels on the same position which is overlapping one on other.

```
//Here is your code
//Check the x-axis and y-axis of both textLabelCustom and detailTextLabelCustom are same.
//It means both label will place on same axis but with different heights.
let textLabelCustom = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 0, 200, 91))
let detailTextLabelCustom = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 0, 200, 20))
let customWebView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(245, 5, 149, 80))
```

Change it like this. And increase you cell size as well.

```
let textLabelCustom = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 0, 200, 90))
let detailTextLabelCustom = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 90, 200, 20))
let customWebView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(245, 5, 149, 80))
```

**Reason 2**

Implement another delegate method `didEndDisplayingCell` and write below line

```
cell.contentView.removeAllSubviews()
```

Comment: How sloppy of me, thank you for pointing that out.  This is embarrassing so I really appreciate your expertise to start moving in the right direction.